# itextsharp - stamp AND add additional page

Tags: powershell

I already have a working snippet for stamping PDF's.
But, now a request has reached me for adding an additional page to the same document.

I have managed to get it working, but I'd like to verify that it is the best way to do it.

Edit: It turns out it is not working as expected.
The fields get malformatted with a big "x" instead of the text as per below image.  If I click the field I can see that the text has been input though.

[image]

Old code

```
$FieldsHash = ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $Fields
$FieldsHash | Export-Clixml C:\Temp\fieldhash.xml

$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader -ArgumentList $InputPdfFilePath
$stamper = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper($reader, [System.IO.File]::Create($OutputPdfFilePath))
            
foreach ($j in $FieldsHash.GetEnumerator())
{
    try {
        $formattedDate = Get-Date $j.Value -Format $DatePattern
        $null = $stamper.AcroFields.SetField($j.Key, $formattedDate)
    }
    catch {
        try {
            $null = $stamper.AcroFields.SetField($j.Key, $j.Value)
        } catch {
            "Could not find $($j.Key)"
        }
    }
}

$stamper.Close()
```

Modified code:

```
$fileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($OutputPdfFilePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate)
$document = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Document
$pdfCopy = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy($document, $fileStream)

$mainreader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($InputPdfFilePath)
$stamper = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper($mainreader, $fileStream)

$document.Open()

$FieldsHash = ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $Fields
$FieldsHash | Export-Clixml C:\Temp\pdf\fieldhash.xml

foreach ($j in $FieldsHash.GetEnumerator())
{
    try {
        $formattedDate = Get-Date $j.Value -Format $DatePattern
        $null = $stamper.AcroFields.SetField($j.Key, $formattedDate)
    } catch {
        try {
            $null = $stamper.AcroFields.SetField($j.Key, $j.Value)
        } catch {
            "Could not find $($j.Key)"
        }
    }
}

$pdfCopy.AddDocument($mainreader)
$mainreader.Dispose()

$attreader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($att)
$pdfCopy.AddDocument($attreader)
$attreader.Dispose()

$pdfCopy.Dispose()
$document.Dispose()
$fileStream.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution, user stamper methods instead:

```
$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader -ArgumentList $InputPdfFilePath
$stamper = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper($reader, [System.IO.File]::Create($OutputPdfFilePath))


foreach ($j in $FieldsHash.GetEnumerator())
{
    try {
        $formattedDate = Get-Date $j.Value -Format $DatePattern
        $null = $stamper.AcroFields.SetField($j.Key, $formattedDate)
    } catch {
        try {
            $null = $stamper.AcroFields.SetField($j.Key, $j.Value)
        } catch {
            "Could not find $($j.Key)"
        }
    }
}

if(Test-Path $attpath) {
    $attreader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($attpath)
    $stamper.InsertPage(3,$attreader.GetPageSize(1))
    $stamper.replacePage($attreader, 1, 3)
    $stamper.Close()
    $reader.Close()
    $attreader.Close()
}
else {
    $stamper.Close()
    $reader.Close()
}
```